# Error : Could not find or load main class Protection

Tags: java, javac

```
package package1;

public class Protection
{
 private int pri=1;
 protected int pro=2;
 public int pub=3;

 public void show()
 {
  System.out.println("Value of private variable is :"+pri);
  System.out.println("Value of protected variable is :"+pro);
  System.out.println("Value of public variable is :"+pub);
 } 
 public static void main(String s[])
 {
  Protection p=new Protection();
  p.show();
  //p.pro=0;
 }
}
```

The above code shows a runtime error indicating :

> Could not find or load class Protection

I have tried and created a package1 folder, but it still does not work at all.

Comment: Please show how you're compiling and running the code, including how the files are laid out on disk.

Comment: Also let us know if you're using IDE and set up build path.

Comment: I think its a path issue .How you are setting the env variable?

Comment: @JonSkeet : The path where files reside is F:\java. I am working on Windows 8.1 machine with Java version 1.8.25. I am compiling via command prompt

F:\java>javac Protection.java

F:\java>java Protection
Error: Could not find or load main class Protection

Comment: @SachinVerma : no IDE used, only notepad++

Comment: You need to give the full qualified name. 
Refer to this answer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18093928/what-does-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-mean

Comment: @yellen : already done that 

F:\java\package1>javac Protection.java

F:\java\package1>java package1.Protection
Error: Could not find or load main class package1.Protection

Comment: Are you running it as java Protection or java Protection.class ?

Comment: @yellen : I tried even Protection.class with and without package too.

F:\java>javac Protection.java

F:\java>java Protection.class
Error: Could not find or load main class Protection.class

F:\java>java package1.Protection.class
Error: Could not find or load main class package1.Protection.class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
F:\java\javac -d . Protection.java
F:\java\java package1.Protection
```

Why does compiling without -d flag fail? That is because the package declaration says class has a package but it is not in the right directory for the run time to execute. Therefore either you have to place the source file Protection.java in package1 directory and go from there as suggested by @Ashutosh or use -d flag so that the generated class file is placed in the right directory structure.

And .. this works with the assumption that your CLASSPATH is empty or has . (current directory) in CLASSPATH.

Comment: Does that mean that though we compile in same directory as the package name, it will still show error? Because the below commands still showed error.

F:\java\package1>javac Protection.java

F:\java\package1>java Protection
Error: Could not find or load main class Protection

Comment: @HarshMadhani Class file should be in the package directory structure from the directory where you run java. If you do what you mentioned in the above comment you should do cd .. to move to F:\java directory and run it from there.

Comment: Does that mean that it does not matter where does the source files (.java) are present, all it matters is where the byte-code(.class) resides for proper execution???

Comment: You can think like that for now. But that does not mean it is not possible to execute class files from other locations. You can do lot of magic by writing your own class loader and load the class from other locations too. However, that is advanced topic. Don't worry about it for now. I brought it up so that you will "remain hungry and remain foolish" (in Steve Jobs' words) and dig more after you learn the fundamentals of java.

Answer (score 1):

Here.. this might help[image]

Follow the things in the screen cdapture

Comment: You should do javac test\Protection.java

Answer (score 0):

I have saved your java file in folder package1 as Protection.java.
In the command prompt from the location where package1 folder is placed ran following command
javac package1/Protection.java

then

java package1.Protection

It's working for me. Please try same steps or try to find what you are missing.

Answer (score 0):

check your class path(F:\java)..that would be two class files having same name.
go through on [What does "Could not find or load main class" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18093928/what-does-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-mean)

Comment: no, there are no two files present in the directory

Comment: okay try F:\java> javac -d . Protection.java                                       F:\java> java package1.Protection